# Insert com pdo e OO

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Tenho a seguinte classe que gerencia banco :

```
<?php
abstract class database{
    /*Método construtor do banco de dados*/
    private function __construct(){}

    /*Evita que a classe seja clonada*/
    private function __clone(){}

    /*Método que destroi a conexão com banco de dados e remove da memória todas as variáveis setadas*/
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->disconnect();
        foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
            unset($this->$key);
        }
    }

    private static $dbtype   = "mysql";
    private static $host     = "localhost";
    private static $port     = "3306";
    private static $user     = "root";
    private static $password = "";
    private static $db       = "PDO";

    /*Metodos que trazem o conteudo da variavel desejada
    @return   $xxx = conteudo da variavel solicitada*/
    private function getDBType()  {return self::$dbtype;}
    private function getHost()    {return self::$host;}
    private function getPort()    {return self::$port;}
    private function getUser()    {return self::$user;}
    private function getPassword(){return self::$password;}
    private function getDB()      {return self::$db;}

    private function connect(){
        try
        {
            $this->conexao = new PDO($this->getDBType().":host=".$this->getHost().";port=".$this->getPort().";dbname=".$this->getDB(), $this->getUser(), $this->getPassword());
        }
        catch (PDOException $i)
        {
            //se houver exceção, exibe
            die("Erro: <code>" . $i->getMessage() . "</code>");
        }

        return ($this->conexao);
    }

    private function disconnect(){
        $this->conexao = null;
    }

    /*Método select que retorna um VO ou um array de objetos*/
    public function selectDB($sql,$params=null,$class=null){
        $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);

        if(isset($class)){
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,$class) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        }else{
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        }
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /*Método insert que insere valores no banco de dados e retorna o último id inserido*/
    public function insertDB($sql,$params=null){
        $conexao=$this->connect();
        $query=$conexao->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $conexao->lastInsertId() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /*Método update que altera valores do banco de dados e retorna o número de linhas afetadas*/
    public function updateDB($sql,$params=null){
        $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $query->rowCount() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /*Método delete que excluí valores do banco de dados retorna o número de linhas afetadas*/
    public function deleteDB($sql,$params=null){
        $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $query->rowCount() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }
}
?>
```

Como posso utilizar o metodo insert. Por exemplo O que passaria na parte param e sql ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma, criando uma classe onde ela ira herdar a classe database, como no seguinte exemplo onde criei a classe LivroDAO:

```
<?php

class LivroDAO extends database {

  public function __construct(){}

  public function insertLivro($data)
  {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tablivro` (`id`, `titulo`, `autor`, `editora`, `anoedicao`, `localizacao`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    parent::insertDB($sql, $data);

  }

  public function deleteLivro($data)
  {

    //...

  }

  public function updateLivro($data)
  {

    //...

  }

  public function selectLivro($data)
  {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablivro` WHERE `id` = ? AND `titulo` = ? AND `anoedicao` = ?";
        $result = parent::selectDB($sql, $data);

        return $result;

  }

}
```

Para fazer o teste você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';
require_once 'LivroDAO.php';

$livroDAO = new LivroDAO();

$dadosLivro = array(
  '10',
  'Livro PHP',
  'João',
  'Novatec',
  '2015',
  'São Paulo',
);

$livroDAO->insertLivro($dadosLivro);
```

Lembrando que você tem que editar a configuração de conexão com o seu banco de dados na classe database, localizada no seguinte trecho de código da classe:

```
...
private static $dbtype   = "mysql";
private static $host     = "localhost";//Seu host do banco de dados
private static $port     = "3306";
private static $user     = "root";
private static $password = "";//Sua senha
private static $db       = "PDO";//Nome do seu banco de dados
...
```

Comment: mas não poderia fazer sem o extend ?

Comment: A não ser que você editar a classe database, não daria porque a classe database é abstract, e classes desse genero não podem ser instanciadas.

Comment: essa logica funciona para o update, select e delete?

Comment: Sim, dar mesmo forma, só implementado esses métodos na classe LivroDAO.

Comment: Amigo, deu errado , retornou Array ( [0] => 42S22 [1] => 1054 [2] => Unknown column 'createData' in 'field list' )

Comment: amigo funcionou, era um erro na digitação do nome de um campo . Obrigado

Comment: Na verdade não deu erro no cógido php e sim na sintaxe do sql de insert, onde está dizendo que o campo createData é desconhecido.

Comment: Sim, agora resolvi trocando o nome... Obg