# select pdo com oo

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo

Tenho esta classe que gerencia o banco de dados :

```
<?php
abstract class database{
    /*Método construtor do banco de dados*/
    private function __construct(){}

    /*Evita que a classe seja clonada*/
    private function __clone(){}

    /*Método que destroi a conexão com banco de dados e remove da memória todas as variáveis setadas*/
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->disconnect();
        foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
            unset($this->$key);
        }
    }

    private static $dbtype   = "mysql";
    private static $host     = "localhost";
    private static $port     = "3306";
    private static $user     = "root";
    private static $password = "";
    private static $db       = "PDO";

    /*Metodos que trazem o conteudo da variavel desejada
    @return   $xxx = conteudo da variavel solicitada*/
    private function getDBType()  {return self::$dbtype;}
    private function getHost()    {return self::$host;}
    private function getPort()    {return self::$port;}
    private function getUser()    {return self::$user;}
    private function getPassword(){return self::$password;}
    private function getDB()      {return self::$db;}

    private function connect(){
        try
        {
            $this->conexao = new PDO($this->getDBType().":host=".$this->getHost().";port=".$this->getPort().";dbname=".$this->getDB(), $this->getUser(), $this->getPassword());
        }
        catch (PDOException $i)
        {
            //se houver exceção, exibe
            die("Erro: <code>" . $i->getMessage() . "</code>");
        }

        return ($this->conexao);
    }

    private function disconnect(){
        $this->conexao = null;
    }

    /*Método select que retorna um VO ou um array de objetos*/
    public function selectDB($sql,$params=null,$class=null){
        $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);

        if(isset($class)){
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,$class) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        }else{
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        }
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /*Método insert que insere valores no banco de dados e retorna o último id inserido*/
    public function insertDB($sql,$params=null){
        $conexao=$this->connect();
        $query=$conexao->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $conexao->lastInsertId() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /*Método update que altera valores do banco de dados e retorna o número de linhas afetadas*/
    public function updateDB($sql,$params=null){
        $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $query->rowCount() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }

    /*Método delete que excluí valores do banco de dados retorna o número de linhas afetadas*/
    public function deleteDB($sql,$params=null){
        $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);
        $rs = $query->rowCount() or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        self::__destruct();
        return $rs;
    }
}
?>
```

Gostaria de saber como posso:

1. Realizar um select com Where
2. acessar o valor retornado para um while ou for
3. Uma função que me retorne a quantidade retornada como o mysql_num_rows

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Insert com pdo e OO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97029/insert-com-pdo-e-oo)

Comment: Não acho que seja duplicata. Certamente as perguntas são parecidas e relacionadas (inclusive com o mesmo autor), mas pedem coisas diferentes. Além disso, a resposta da outra pergunta não responde essa daqui. E certamente que o autor da pergunta não criaria uma outra pergunta com o mesmo propósito sendo que ele já teve a sua outra dúvida respondida e aceitou a resposta dada.

Comment: Usar uma coisa pronta pode ser melhor ainda:  [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) ou [RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faz da seguinte forma usando a classe LivroDAO como exemplo que eu criei em outro questão usando essa mesma classe database:

```
class LivroDAO extends database {

  public function __construct(){}

  public function insertLivro($data)
  {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tablivro` (`id`, `titulo`, `autor`, `editora`, `anoedicao`, `localizacao`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    parent::insertDB($sql, $data);

  }

  public function deleteLivro($data)
  {

    //...

  }

  public function updateLivro($data)
  {

    //...

  }

  public function selectLivro($data)
  {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablivro` WHERE `id` = ? AND `titulo` = ? AND `anoedicao` = ?";
    $result = parent::selectDB($sql, $data);

    return $result;

  }

}
```

Teste de uso:

```
<?php

require_once 'database.php';
require_once 'LivroDAO.php';

$dadosLivro = array(
  '10',
  'Livro PHP',
  2015,
);

$livroDAO = new LivroDAO();

$result = $livroDAO->selectLivro($dadosLivro);

foreach($result as $r){
    var_dump($r);
}

foreach($result as $r){

    echo 'id: ' . $r->id . '<br>';
    echo 'titulo: ' . $r->titulo . '<br>';
    echo 'autor: ' . $r->autor . '<br>';
    echo 'editora: ' . $r->editora . '<br>';
    echo 'anoedicao: ' . $r->anoedicao . '<br>';
    echo 'localizacao: ' . $r->localizacao . '<br>';

}

//Quantidade de itens retornados
echo 'Quantidade de itens: ' . count($result);
```

Resultado:

```
object(stdClass)[4]
  public 'id' => string '10' (length=2)
  public 'titulo' => string 'Livro PHP' (length=9)
  public 'autor' => string 'JoÃ£o' (length=5)
  public 'editora' => string 'Novatec' (length=7)
  public 'anoedicao' => string '2015' (length=4)
  public 'localizacao' => string 'SÃ£o Paulo' (length=10)

Quantidade de itens: 1
```

Comment: Amigo o que seria o var_dump?

Comment: Ela só é uma função que retorna em forma de String(texto) as informações sobre uma variável passada como argumento, como nesse caso ela está mostrando tudo que está dentro da variável $r, que é uma linha de registro da tabela do banco de dados.

Comment: Entendi , obrigado

Comment: amigo, mais uma pergunta como posso exibir um resultado especifico, pois se colocar $result[titulo] da errado...

Comment: Faz assim: $r->titulo, verifica também que eu mudei o código acima mostrando como você pode fazer isso.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Para pegar o número de linhas retornadas sugiro que crie uma propriedade `$rowCount` ela terá se valor mudado sempre que um select for executado.

O que muda de um select com where para um sem é se será informado algum argumento para `execute()` nesse caso um if resolve.

```
$public $rowCount;

function select($sql, $params=null, $class=null){
    $query = $this->conexao->prepare($sql);
    if($params){
        $query->execute($params);
    }else{
        $query->execute();
    }

    $this->rowCount = $query->rowCount();
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

Como deve ser a chamada do novo código.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE c1 = ? AND c2 = ? AND c3 = ?";
$param = array(51, 'userName', 2015);
$registros = select($sql, $param);

foreach($registros as $item){
    echo $item['campo'] .'<br>';
}
```

Sua classe já tem um propriedade para guardar a conexão(objeto PDO) evite criar novas sem necessidade.

```
public function selectDB($sql,$params=null,$class=null){
   $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
```